# Hash with duplicate key values

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm writing a small script for checking for repeated files inside a folder. I did with array, and i was successful. The problem is that i want to store the folder location also, so i can see where the duplicated files are.

My first thought was using a Hash. But since you will have a lot of files in the same folder, I can't do: hash[folder] = file. The reverse is also impossivel, because if I have repeated files, they will be overwritten (hash[file] = folder)

So what is the best approach to do that?

My code:

```
class FilesList

 attr_accessor :elements

 def initialize(path)
    @elements = Hash.new
    @path = path
    printDirectory(@path)
 end

 def printDirectory(folderPath) 
 entries = Dir.entries(folderPath) - [".", "..", "repeat.rb"]
 entries.each do |single|
        if File.directory?("#{folderPath}/#{single}")
            printDirectory("#{folderPath}/#{single}")
        else
            @elements[single] = folderPath
        end
    end
 end

 def printArray
    puts @elements
 end

 def each()
    @elements.each do |x, y|
        yield x y
    end
end

def checkRepeated
    if @elements.length == @elements.keys.uniq.length
        puts "No repeated Files"
    else
        counts = Hash.new(0)
        @elements.each do |key,val|
            counts[val] += 1
        end
        repeateds = counts.reject{|val,count|count==1}.keys
        puts repeateds
    end
end

end

array = FilesList.new(Dir.pwd)

array.printArray
```

Answer (score 1):

You may store arrays (or [sets](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html)) of file names (or folder paths) as hash values

For example, in your code you may change `@elements[single] = folderPath` to:

```
@elements[single] ||= []
@elements[single] << folderPath
```

And then later, your `val`'s will be arrays of folders where file was met.

Comment: Still doesn't help. I can have multiple folder names or multiple file names, so i can't store the file name(single) as a key in one hash

Comment: I would just set the default value of the hash to be an array: `@elements = Hash.new([])`

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the above, but don't use the file as the key.

```
@elements = Hash.new([])

entries.each do |single|
  if File.directory?("#{folderPath}/#{single}")
    printDirectory("#{folderPath}/#{single}")
  else
    @elements[folderPath] << single
  end
end
```

Then you'll get something that looks like this:

```
{ '/path1' => ['awesome_file.rb', 'beautiful.js'],
  '/path2' => ['beautiful.js', 'coffee.rb'] }
```

And then, if I understand you correctly, you can find duplicate files like so:

```
files = @elements.values.flatten
repeateds = files.select{ |file| files.count(file) > 1 }
```

This will return an array: `["beautiful.js", "beautiful.js"]`, which you can call `.uniq` on to just get the one `["beautiful.js"`, or do a count if you like, or map the results to another hash that tells you how often it's repeated, etc.